# How to get an image's Exif information using Adobe ExtendScript?

Tags: adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I'm writing a script for adding image's EXIF information into After Effects as text layer, how can I retrieve an image's EXIF information using ExtendScript Toolkit? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since AE doesn't offer any tools for reading exif data natively, there won't be any built-in methods in extendscript. But you could use a command-line exif tool like [libexif](https://libexif.github.io/) and then call it using a [system call](https://github.com/ExtendScript/wiki/wiki/System-Call) from extendscript.

If you're distributing the result, obviously you'll have to check the license and compatibility of whatever tool you use.